# regex exclude nested html tag

Tags: php, regex

i have a piece of text:

```
<strong>blalblalba</strong>blasldasdsadasdasd<strong> 3.5m Euros<br>
<span class="style6">SOLD</span></strong>
```

and I want to remove `<strong> contains $|euros|Euros</strong>`

So far I have:

```
preg_replace('#<strong>.*?(^<strong>).*?(\$|euros|Euros|EUROS).*?</strong>#is', '', $result);
```

but it is not working... I was trying also negative lock head (?!) but still not working...

Any help? Thanks

Comment: A regex is too difficult for this/you. Try one of the [simpler alternatives](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/how-do-you-parse-and-process-html-xml-in-php).

Comment: A little more specific in what you're trying to remove would help.

Comment: I'm curious the intention of the ^ here `'#<strong>.*?(^`  since I believe that indicates "beginning of the string" and will cause this to never match.

Comment: well ^ also can mean not include? sorry I edited question :D coz <strong> was missinterpreted

Comment: afaik ^ means "not include" only when inside [square brackets] not (parens)

Answer (score 1):

With the assumption you expect two stong's before your Euros, I think this may be what you want: `preg_replace('#^<strong>.*?<strong>.*?(\$[euros|Euros|EUROS]).*?</strong>#is', '', $result);`

Comment: then try this `preg_replace('#.*(<strong>.*?\$[euros|Euros|EUROS].*?</strong>)#is', '', $result);`

Comment: this works on my server for your input string (removed $ since not in your example) `preg_replace('#</strong>.*(<strong>.*[euros|Euros|EUROS].*?</strong>)#is', '', $result);`

Comment: not working at all please, this can not work because you have euros in []... so it means that it will match letters, also your approach is not good because </strong>.* will replace also characters outside nested <strong> element

Comment: nope only what is inside inner parens gets replaces, as i said it works on my server with your example, and you are giving contradictory requests as to what you're attempting.  i suspect mario's comment above is correct.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this, must use 'Dot-All' modifier or substitute [\S\s]  -

```
 # <strong>(?:(?!\1)(?:\$|euros|Euros|EUROS)()|(?!<strong>).)+</strong>\1

 <strong>
 (?:
      (?! \1 )
      (?: \$ | euros | Euros | EUROS )
      ( )
   |  
      (?! <strong> )
      . 
 )+
 </strong>
 \1
```